# Strange Java NullPointer with SQLlite and JavaFX initialization - paths? (Maven)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, javafx

I've got a problem with my project and we didn't find a matching solution yet:

Our project is written in JAVA, uses JAVAFX 1.8 and SQLlite as DB. We use maven to build our jars. The pom is attached at the bottom. A good point is maybe, that we're using internalization of JavaFX and are getting our ResourceBoundles from the SQLlite db too.

Our program is working great when startet in eclipse but does not work at all when started from the jar.

Just to get you into: As we need a DB, we initialize one if no db file exists. In this step, the running of the programm gives all the necessery checks like Tables checked, db filled a.s.o.. It also creates the db file next to the .jar but afterwards - when the db should be accessed we're getting a NullPointer without(!?) StackTrace.

I tried to launch the .jar with copying the existing and working db from the eclipse project before. The routine gets some steps further, but as I want to get live information (SELECT something...) from the db, the program ends in a catch block, saying it could not search in the db.

Do you maybe have any clue how I can debug this? Or at least how I could reproduce it in eclipse?

Some more thoughts: It is interesting that if I go in a menu where a graph which is stored in the db is drawn, everything works... I even can manipulate the location of the nodes, restart the program and the db gets it.
BUT if I want to search for a node the given Error under the pom is thrown.
And If I change the language the well known NullPointer apears again...

It seems that it could have a problem with the language resources. One more thought which came up when I wanted to add an background image to the given graph is, that it might have problems with the paths in the project, because we had those already - the well known .getResource() struggle.. (.pom updated)

Thanks!

First Edit: Had a mistake in the .pom: After adding the correct versionentry of the sqlite driver the runnig improved. Language is now working, but the mentioned NullPointer is still there. I also can not import or load background images for some reason...

**25.07.: The program is working correctly now if a db file exists. But only if the db file is created in eclipse. If I want to run it without db, meaning it should create the db on its own, it does couple of things, but then gets the described NullPointer.**

**After some debugging with Sysprints I found out that it seems to be a problem with the languages. We're importing a .xml file into the .db witch contains the existing strings for the language. It seems that this file is not loaded properly but I have no idea how to check what is wrong :-/**

```
    try {
        // ResourceBundle bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(inputStream);
        // Loader to load FXML, sets the location of the choose map view
        // fxml file via parameter.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

        loader.setResources(this.mainHandler.getIOHandler().getLanguage(
                locale));
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(
                ViewPathEnum.CHOOSE_MAP.getPath()));

        // container for all the Items of the choose map view.
        Pane chooseMapHBox = null;

        // loads the fxml file for the mapchoose view.
        chooseMapHBox = loader.load();
```

.pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>pse15-group1</groupId>
  <artifactId>carp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>carp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.10.1</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                       <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>pse15group1.carp.controller.MainController</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>pse15group1.carp.controller.MainController</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And one of the ould Errors which **is fixed, problem was wrong sqlite version...**:

```
C:\....>java -jar carp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Opened database successfully
Table Map checked succesfully
Table Metrics checked succesfully
Table Node checked succesfully
Table Edge checked succesfully
Table Tag checked succesfully
Table MetricsEdge checked succesfully
Table Language checked succesfully
Table LanguageData checked succesfully
Opened database successfully
Table Map checked succesfully
Table Metrics checked succesfully
Table Node checked succesfully
Table Edge checked succesfully
Table Tag checked succesfully
Table MetricsEdge checked succesfully
Table Language checked succesfully
Table LanguageData checked succesfully
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (ambiguous c
olumn name: map_ID)
        at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
        at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
        at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
        at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
        at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
        at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeQuery(Stmt.java:121)
        at pse15group1.carp.model.io.SqlConnector.searchNodes(SqlConnector.java:
190)
```

Comment: A `NullPointerException` _without_ a stacktrace? Are you sure that it is _actually_ an exception? I mean: Is it something you can actually catch in your code into a Throwable object (which you should introspect to know its stacktrace), or maybe it is just a message logged to the console?

Comment: `[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (ambiguous c
olumn name: map_ID)`: This error seems enoughly verbose to research it. What is been executed at SqlConnector.java:190?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

@LittleSanti I tried some things, I'll add it to the question in a minute.